# Passagem de parâmetros de uma página para outra em PHP

Tags: php, post

Tenho uma listagem de dados em uma página. Ali uma 'imagem de edição' serve como link para outra página onde esses dados sao exibidos novamente (além dos demais dados do cliente) e é possível fazer a edição dos mesmos. Como segue, a página destino é editar.php

nesse link quero passar por parametro o ID do cliente para que na tela editar.php eu possa manipular esse cliente e exibir novamente seus dados. Tudo via POST.

havia pensado em algo como: href="editar.php?fields('id_usuario'); ?>"

Comment: Quer postar o código pra gente dar uma olhada?

Comment: Mas este método que você colocou ali é via GET, via POST é diferente... Mas você pode fazer dessa forma sim, ai só na sua consulta busque WHERE id = $_GET['id'];, editar.php?id=id_usuario

Comment: $sql = select" aqui faz o select dos dados no banco ";
$usuarios = Consulta($sql, $conexao);

até aqui tudo certo. tá pegando os valores na base e exibindo na tela em uma lista. para cada nome exibido na lista, aparece um link para clicar e editar, onde é aberta uma nova tela com esses campos já preenchidos e disponiveis para edição.

o link que leva para a nova tela é:

<a href="editar.php?id=<? $usuarios->fields('id_usuario'); ?>"><div class="col" style="width:25px" align="left"><img src="edit.png" alt="Editar" name="id"></div></a>

passando o parametro dessa forma nao esta funcionando

Comment: Posta como pergunta @PHPdeveloper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo,

pra você enviar o id_usuario via post, terá que enviar com ajax.

Seria mais ou menos isso:

```
$('#link').click(function(e){  
                e.preventDefault();
                var valores = $('#link').serialize()
                console.log(valores);
                $.ajax({
                url : editar.php',
                type: 'post',
                dataType : 'html',
                data: valores,
                beforeSend : function(){
                    $('#carregando').show('100');
                },
                //colocamos o retorno na tela
                    success : function(pre){
                        $('#carregando').hide('100');
                        $('#retorno').find('strong').text(pre).end().show(100);
                    } 
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Um detalhe! terás que recuperar o id no ajax como um data e enviar para o editar.php. Acredito que com algumas pequenas alterações você consegui ter exito nessa aplicação.